# Check if Data Attribute Exists, Find Matching Value in Another Tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-feed

I'm having trouble with a twitter feed due to a combination of how twitter shortens links and how it handles media entities. Right now, if a tweet has an image, the tweet's li in my feed is being populated with both the image and a link to the image's photo page. I would like to get rid of the image link.

The way the script is set up (I've been working from [this one](https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie/pull/34)), I've started by inserting the image's url (which is different from its media_url that is used to create the image src) into a data-source attribute within the image tag. That url is the same as the href value in the link I want to get rid of. So I just need to find the data-source attribute (if the tweet contains one), get its value, find the matching href value, and hide the anchor that contains it.

Unfortunately, I don't have a fiddle, but here is an example of a tweet's templating data (I copied it from an alert):

```
<p class="author">TENNIS.com</p>
The #AusOpen in pictures: all the best images from the season's first Slam. PHOTOS:
<a href="https://t.co/pbx4viaipB" target="_blank" title="https://t.co/pbx4viaipB">[view]</a>
<a href="https://t.co/9KaZNWUP8N" target="_blank" title="https://t.co/9KaZNWUP8N">[view]</a>
<img src='http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CaTVJq4W4AAkQbT.png' data-source='https://t.co/9KaZNWUP8N' />
<p class="stamp"><span class="date">February 3, 2016</span> RT <a href="http://twitter.com/Tennis" target="_blank" title="Tennis on Twitter">@Tennis</a> on 2/3</p>
```

(That first link is a part of the tweet; the second one is the image that's already embedded.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple cycle will do.

For each image we grab the `data-source`.

Then we search for all the links that have that as an href `$('a[href="data-source"]')`;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function(i) {
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('data-source') + '"]').hide();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="author">TENNIS.com</p>
The #AusOpen in pictures: all the best images from the season's first Slam. PHOTOS:
<a href="https://t.co/pbx4viaipB" target="_blank" title="https://t.co/pbx4viaipB">[view]</a>
<a href="https://t.co/9KaZNWUP8N" target="_blank" title="https://t.co/9KaZNWUP8N">[view]</a>
<img src='http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CaTVJq4W4AAkQbT.png' data-source='https://t.co/9KaZNWUP8N' />
<p class="stamp"><span class="date">February 3, 2016</span> RT <a href="http://twitter.com/Tennis" target="_blank" title="Tennis on Twitter">@Tennis</a> on 2/3</p>
```

Also, we are using a cycle here because I presume that you will have different tweets in your feed. Else instead of the `each()` you can select that single image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joel. That solved it perfectly. (and yes, there are multiple tweets)